# StoreKit 2 and change of business model

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have implemented a change in the business model of my iOS app, following this documentation from apple: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/supporting_business_model_changes_by_using_the_app_transaction

I made sure that only iOS 16+ users can download the app by putting iOS 16 as minimum target. I have implemented this function:

```
func checkOriginalVersion() async {
    
    if #available(iOS 16, *) {
        
        do {
            // Get the appTransaction.
            let shared = try await AppTransaction.shared
            if case .verified(let appTransaction) = shared {
                // Hard-code the major version number in which the app's business model changed.
                let newBusinessModelMajorVersion = "2"

                // Get the major version number of the version the customer originally purchased.
                let versionComponents = appTransaction.originalAppVersion.split(separator: ".")
                let originalMajorVersion = versionComponents[0]

                print("Original version:  ", originalMajorVersion)
                
                if originalMajorVersion < newBusinessModelMajorVersion {
                    print("Already purchased")
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "hasPurchased")
                }
                else {
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "hasPurchased")
                }
            }
        }
        catch {
            
            // Handle errors.
        }
    }
}
```

And I call it in viewDidAppear

```
Task {
        
        if !UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "hasPurchased") {
            await checkOriginalVersion()
        }
```

Now, here is the very disappointing aspect. When I test this using Xcode, it works perfectly. When I tested it with my beta testers via testflight, it also works well. However, after releasing it to the App Store, it doesn't work!

Do you have any insights on why this happens? I will now prepare myself to the of 1- star reviews that will kill my business :(

Comment: Wanted to share the observation that "appTransaction.originalAppVersion" seems to return the build number rather than the version. The property name and Apples documentation (and example code!!) clearly points towards it returning a version.

Comment: Hi, are you sure about that? This would explain many things... however, I still see inconsistent behavior among users... at the moment, it seems random! In the next update, I will log the results of "appTransaction.originalAppVersion" on my database to get more insights... I will keep you guys updated

Comment: Hi ... did you find the problem?

Comment: Nope, somehow when I tried to log the appTransaction.originalAppVersion, the app was crashing in production. Related to my post, the results I was getting are obvious. In TestFlight or Xcode (sandbox environment), the originalAppVersion is always 1.0... So, another layer of frustration :(. These things are extremely hard to test...

Answer (score 0):

So, I finally figured this out.

```
appTransaction.originalAppVersion
```

returns the original build number, not the version. The documentation is, to say the least, confusing. Also, why call it "originalAppVersion" if it returns the build number. Anyway, we should just keep track of the build number and it should work.

Comment: Not only that, the API behavior is completely inconsistent across platforms. On macOS (even on Mac Catalyst builds) it returns the expected marking version (ie. 1.X.X from the CFBundleShortVersionString), but on iOS it returns the build version (from CFBundleVersion) ‍♂️

Feedback Reports: FB12222361, FB12222348, FB12218576